# Restrict access to Amazon S3 static webpage to only registered users

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a PHP e-commence website that sells e-books.

Each e-book is stored on Amazon S3 as a static HTML webpage, which also links to a number of CSS, JS and font files.

For example:
https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/university-revision-guru/example/index.html#page=1

I want to be able to restrict access to this file such that only specific registered users in my database can access it. How can I do this?

It seems like Amazon S3 permission property only allows access to specific AWS accounts, IP addresses OR completely public. Therefore, it is clear I will probably have to do some work on the application end.

How can I restrict access to an Amazon S3 static webpage such that only specific registered users in my database can access it?

Answer (score 3):

You could make the bucket private and every time a user wants to view the book require them to login to your website to get the link. Then have your PHP app generate a [S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html) when a user requests the link.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple 5step guide to do it.

1. Integrate [aws php sdk](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) into your application.

   2. Store the S3 key for each book.
   3. Control the ebook urls through your website. Something like  http://your-website.com/ebook.php?book='wings-of-fire&book-id=123.
      (you will manage the user's security and acls here)
   4. Using the book Id or name, find the corresponding S3 key.
   5. Using the aws php sdk, get the file content (you can either get the content from aws and send it as an attachment to the user or
      generate a pre signed url and redirect user to that url)  Here is
      how to [get object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-s3-2006-03-01.html#getobject) and here is how to get [pre-signed-url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/service/s3-presigned-url.html).

Answer (score 0):

you might take a look at Amazon Cognito for your security problems, i found an answer that might be what you need take a look at:
[Amazon Cognito S3](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html)